# is ROS industrial supported on ABB IRB 6400 m97a controller?

Tags: ros, abb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello, i'm new to this, and at my school we have an old IRB 6400 Robot and controller, what i want to know is, if is posible to stablish the comunication between ROS industrial and this controller, And what will it take to do this.

i dont have many info about this divices, but the manual
link:[Manual](http://www.google.com.mx/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiEosDeupnLAhWMvYMKHSEfDR0QFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpergatory.mit.edu%2Fkinematiccouplings%2Fcase_studies%2Fabb_robotics%2Fgeneral%2F6400r%2520product%2520manual.pdf&usg=AFQjCNH3J82YPt6CvbjpQLs9-1GnJw98Jw&bvm=bv.115339255,d.amc)[irb 6400]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227741/is-ros-industrial-supported-on-abb-irb-6400-m97a-controller?/) by [davidmangas](https://answers.ros.org/users/26099/davidmangas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see the [wiki/abb/Tutorials/InstallServer](http://wiki.ros.org/abb/Tutorials/InstallServer) page and [Is ROS industrial supported on ABB's IRB 1520 or IRB 1600 robots ?](http://answers.ros.org/question/200272/is-ros-industrial-supported-on-abbs-irb-1520-or-irb-1600-robots/) for what is needed in general to support a particular ABB robot.

In your particular case, I think the old controller may be problematic: if I understand you correctly, you have an S4C controller. The RAPID components of the driver were developed and tested on IRC5 controllers, so I'm not sure they are compatible.

I'd advise you to send a message to the [ROS-Industrial mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/swri-ros-pkg-dev) and see whether someone has already tried this. If not, readers there might be able to help you.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gustaffson](https://answers.ros.org/users/40344/gustaffson/) on 2019-03-05**:
Hi there,

Did you ever solve this?
I also would like to control an IRB 6400R through ROS

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-06**:
The limitation here is the controller, not the specific manipulator.

**Comment by [Gustaffson](https://answers.ros.org/users/40344/gustaffson/) on 2019-03-06**:
The problem we are having is that the memory of the controller is very limited, we would like to find a way to bypass the controller and control the manipulator via a computer. We thought using ROS-I might be a way to do this. Have you seen this done before?
Shall I message the mailing list?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-06**:\

> bypass the controller and control the manipulator via a computer. We thought using ROS-I might be a way to do this.

No, that is not something the driver supports and is also not a goal of ROS-I (integration, not replacement).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-06**:
Unless I misunderstood you and your goal is to "drip feed" trajectories to the controller.

In that case it would be possible, but you'll have to change the driver.

The mailing list is deprecated, please use the [Discourse category](https://discourse.ros.org/c/ros-industrial).

**Comment by [Gustaffson](https://answers.ros.org/users/40344/gustaffson/) on 2019-03-06**:
Correct me if I'm wrong,this is how I have it in mind:
With ABB ROS Server installed on the controller I can send commands to the controler that then executes these commands (manipulator moves). I can send these commands w/ my laptop.
This way I am working around the memory problem on the controller

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-06**:
That is what "drip feeding" means, yes.

But the current driver implements a *downloading* approach, which means it caches entire trajectories on the controller before executing them.

So that'll have to change.

Perhaps someone has already done that, so a post to Discourse might be worthwhile.

**Comment by [Gustaffson](https://answers.ros.org/users/40344/gustaffson/) on 2019-03-06**:
Glad to know I was looking in the right direction. The last people working on the project were drip feeding from a FTP server and they indeed were bumping into the problem of the download approach.
I will put a post out on the Discorse, I also hope that the ABB ROS Server works on a S4C.

**Comment by [Gustaffson](https://answers.ros.org/users/40344/gustaffson/) on 2019-03-06**:
Thanks for the help I appreciate it!